# Return specific Row first and then other Row follow

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sql

I want to print the trending row first and then New and then all other row from the table "employee".

Also i want limit the number of row and in descending order

I was trying this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 7) sub ORDER BY id DESC
```

[image: TU]

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Based on the preponderance of tags, I removed mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try ordering with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT id, Name, Status
FROM employee
ORDER BY
    CASE Status WHEN 'Trending' THEN 1
                WHEN 'NEW' THEN 2
                ELSE 3 END,
    id DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: It fetching all the row look like Limit function is not working and Yes condition work fine

Comment: `LIMIT 7` can only return 7 or fewer rows, leading me to suggest that you are not actually running the query in my answer.